# "Undefined is not an Object" error on AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to save stringed information now, but the following error appears.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluation '_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.setItem')

There is Functional Code.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export function addStack(stackID, stackName, stackCalender, stackFeedback, stackDeadline, stackStorage) {
  const stackData = ({ stackID, stackName, stackCalender, stackFeedback, stackDeadline, stackStorage });
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('stack', JSON.stringify(stackData));
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
};

addStack.propTypes = {
  stackID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  stackName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  stackCalender: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  stackFeedback: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  stackDeadline: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  stackStorage: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

and The triggers that use that function are shown below.

```
export default class StackPanel extends Component {  
  
  state = {
    stackName: '',
    calEnable: false,
    feedEnable: false,
    deadEnable: false,
    storageEnable: false,
    check: false,
  };

  Check = (checked) => {
    this.setState({ check: true });
    const date = new Date();
    const formattedDate = moment(date).format("YYYYMMDDhhmmss");
    addStack(formattedDate, this.state.stackName, this.state.calEnable, this.state.feedEnable, this.state.deadEnable, this.state.storageEnable, this.state.check);
  };
```

(It's not written in that state, but there are other things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use the correct method for importing.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

This `module` is not exported as a `react-native`, so it must not have a square bracket.

Use in `react-native` module like this:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```